# Fragments make Retrofit request again when switches back to the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have bottom navigation bar implemented in `MainActivity` class having two fragments. I am making Retrofit request in both fragments problem is when I am switching fragments and coming back to the  previous one then it makes request again and previous data has lost. I don't want this I want data to be persist in fragments once request is made.

Below is my code:

**MainActivity.class**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Home");

    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    bottomBar = findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);

    bottomBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

           switch(item.getItemId()){

               case R.id.navigation_home:

                   HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
                   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                   fragmentTransaction.commit();

                   toolbar.setTitle("Home");

                   return true;

               case R.id.navigation_video:

                   VideoFragment fragment1 = new VideoFragment();
                   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                   fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.container, fragment1);
                   fragmentTransaction1.commit();

                   toolbar.setTitle("Videos");

                   return true;
           }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

**HomeFragment.class**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    recycle = view.findViewById(R.id.recycle);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recycle.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recycle.setHasFixedSize(true);

    loadFacts();

     return view;

 }
```

**VideoFragment.class**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video, container, false);

    recycle = view.findViewById(R.id.recycle);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recycle.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recycle.setHasFixedSize(true);

    loadVideos();

    return view;

 }
```

How can I get my desired result?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem here is you use fragmentTransaction.replace. So when you switch tab. It destroy current fragment and add a new fragment, your fragment create again. To solve this I recommend to use viewpager.

Comment: Is there anyway to overcome this problem using bottom navigation bar

Comment: bottom navigation bar is just a view to show your fragment position. It not hold your fragment. Here is an example using viewpager + bottom navigation: https://droidmentor.com/bottomnavigationview-with-viewpager-android/. Another way is using navigation component https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your data you can cache them to a Repository. Each time you need your data check if the data already exist, if not download them again.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the fragment lifecycle, while recreating it starts from `onCreateView` and `onAttach` & `onCreate` are called only when fragment is creating for first time. So, what you can do is

1. Make the API call and initialization of all variables, data of which you want to persist, in `onCreate` method only.
2. Use `ViewModel` instead as it retains it's state even if fragment is recreated.

If both the fragments are shown as two tabs, I hope you've implemented them using `ViewPager` only. It retains the state by default if you swipe in between two fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Make A common class and make a static variable that stores whether the page is visited first time or later and if it is visited later then dont load data else load data.

In Common class make a boolean variable

```
public static boolean first=false;
```

Then In Your Activity do this

```
if(Common.first==false)
{
Common.first=true;
loadVideos();
}
else
{
//dont load list
}
```